# SQL Admin API Export taking longer than it used to, causing timeout problems, is this a bug?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm using the Java SQL Admin API v1beta4 rev5.
We have had code running on older versions of this API since summer 2014 without issue. The problem is, small Export operations that used to complete in a few seconds now always take just over 1 minute (exceeding the App Engine timeout response time limit of 60 sec by just a few seconds). We use small exports and imports to provide template databases for our customers. They are always small (schema for under 12 tables and only sample data) and previously always exported and imported in just a few seconds. We would start the export and then poll the GCS bucket for the object every few seconds until the file was available. This worked reliably for 9+ months.

However, recently, the exported object started to appear in the GCS bucket (indicating that the export had indeed finished and the .sql file was available) but the operation status of the export is still "RUNNING", so any call to import from that file generated a "403 Operation failed because another operation was already in progress" error message.

I am hoping this is a bug and not an architecture change in the SQL Admin API... **ideally the operation status should change to DONE when the operation is done, not at some arbitrary length of time after it has actually completed**.

Is this a bug?

Code below in case its helpful:

```
ExportContext.SqlExportOptions exportOptions = new ExportContext.SqlExportOptions()
            .setTables( new ArrayList<String>(tableNames) );

        ExportContext exportContext = new ExportContext()
            .setDatabases(Arrays.asList(srcDatabase))
            .setFileType("SQL")
            .setUri(dumpUri)
            .setSqlExportOptions(exportOptions);

        InstancesExportRequest exportRequest = new InstancesExportRequest().setExportContext(exportContext);

        Operation op = this.sqlAdmin.instances().export(AuthUtils.GAE_PROJECT_NAME, nakedSrcInstance, exportRequest).execute();
```

Comment: I can confirm that even small export operations are reported as terminated after more than one minute. :-( Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for bringing this to our attention. We are working on fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I was running some exports myself and noticed that they were taking a bit over a minute. To get the actual time stamp, I went into the Developers Console and ran the Operations:list API [1]. I was able to see the actual time.

```
"operationType": "EXPORT",
"status": "DONE",
"insertTime": "2015-04-17T22:03:28.745Z",
"startTime": "2015-04-17T22:03:29.023Z",
"endTime": "2015-04-17T22:04:29.286Z",
```

Best thing to do is to report the issue on the following website [2] and Google will look into it.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/operations/list

[2] https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/list

Comment: Thanks. Just did that.